# How to Assess Multicollinearity for Independent Count and Rate Variables

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, count-data, variance-inflation-factor

How do I test an independent variable for multicollinearity if it comes from a Poisson or Negative Binomial distribution?

A common approach for testing the multicollinearity of a model's independent variables is to calculate the Variance Inflation Factor of each independent variable by running a separate regression model with one of the independent variables as the focal variable and regress it against all of the other independent variables to get its Rsquared. Then the focal independent variable's VIF is calculated as 1 / (1 - Rsquared).

But what if my focal independent variable is count and not continuous (e.g., number of primary care visits per month)? How would I test this variable for multicollinearity?

Comment: Why would you test multicollinearity? Why not just run the outcome model and report the results? Multicollinearity is a feature of universe (i.e., of the data), not something you need to correct or prevent.

Comment: @Noah my understanding is that multicollinearity can affect the coefficients and standard errors of a regression model, which can cause misinterpretation of the affected variable's effect on the response.

Comment: Since multicollinearity is a mathematical property of the linear relations among variables (which is purely a matter of how those variables are employed in the model), (1) you don't "test" it--you *measure* it or *assess* its potential effects on your results--and (2) it makes no difference what types of data these variables might be or even (to a great extent) what kind of model it is.  BTW, condition numbers and diagnostics more directly related to them tend to be more useful than VIF.